# "New style getargs format but argument is not a tuple" Pillow image paste error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm using the Pillow library to create randomized bingo sheets of Game of Thrones characters for my friends, and created a PNG background sheet to paste thumbnails of the images I found on to. However, when I go to paste my picture of random Game of Thrones character (let's say Arya) onto my background image and define the area used to paste, I get the error "new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple" and the code fails.

I was using Python 3.6.6 and I tried 3.6.5 as well, using both Pip and Conda to reinstall Pillow on each version (now have Pillow 5.1.0 and Pillow 6.0.0) I've tried writing the paste coordinates directly instead of using a variable, and changing the types of image I'm pasting onto and pasting directly from PNG to JPEG to see if that would change the way it defined the coordinates, with no luck.

I've also tried recasting the variable as a tuple although it already is, still didn't work. In the documentation it said if you left the area blank it should automatically past the top left corner to (0,0) but when I do that I get an error telling me to input the box coordinates. It also said if you use a tuple of 2 instead of 4 coordinates it should work, but that returned an error telling me to use a tuple of 4.

```
bingo = Image.new("RGB",(740,740), color=(10,10,10))

size = 128,128
arya = Image.open("arya_edit.jpg")              #arya 1
arya = arya.thumbnail(size)

box = (10,10,138,138)
#tried box = tuple(box) 
bingo.paste(arya, box)
```

Arya's photo should take up the top left corner of the background image, but just returns the error every time. I don't understand where this error is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code isn't with the `paste` line, but with how you're making your thumbnail. The [`Image.thumbnail` method](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.thumbnail) modifies an `Image` in place, and returns `None`, so when you run `arya = arya.thumbnail(size)`, you're overwriting your reference to the newly resized image with `None`, which is certainly not what you intended.

That `None` value breaks your later code in the way you have described. You can avoid it by just calling `thumbnail` without assigning its return value to anything:

```
arya = Image.open("arya_edit.jpg")
arya.thumbnail(size)               # don't assign here, it modifies the image in place
```